Python Django : ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\ADMİN\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 173, in finish_response
    super().finish_response()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 292, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 466, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 834, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1274, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1243, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)


Hello Friends
The problem I have is that the SSL Error error in the python layer is caught and processed in the Django layer. Here is the issue: We are developing a project in Python Django environment. We are using openssl for runsslserver architecture. We have designed an advanced logging architecture for this situation. However, despite prioritizing middelware first, we could not catch and log this ssl error. Thank you in advance to anyone who has ideas or suggestions on this issue.
class SSLErrorMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # İstek başladığında ve bittiğinde sinyalleri bağla
        request_started.connect(self.log_request_start)
        request_finished.connect(self.log_request_finish)

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Request processing
        try:
            response = self.get_response(request)
        except ssl.SSLEOFError as e:
            error_details = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.error(f"SSL EOF Error at {request.path}: {str(e)} | Traceback: {error_details}")
            return HttpResponse("SSL connection error occurred.", status=503)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Unexpected error at {request.path}: {str(e)} | Traceback: {traceback.format_exc()}")
            raise e
        return response

    @staticmethod
    @receiver(request_started)
    def log_request_start(sender, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(f"Request started signal received.")

    @staticmethod
    @receiver(request_finished)
    def log_request_finish(sender, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(f"Request finished signal received.")

    def get_error_details(self):
        stack_trace = traceback.format_exc()
        return f"Traceback: {stack_trace}"

